# How to choose the correct ARM chip and understanding the pins at a more intuitive level?

Tags: embedded, arm, bluetooth

I'm just starting out my journey developing my own board and need some advice how to get started and understand a few things in better context.

I will ask my first question first and provide the preconditions- I need to create a board that supports: bluetooth, audio out, LCD  screen, camera, various LEDs. Those are the preconditions; from what I understand ARM Cortex M7 would work quite well for this but do not want to over-do it and need some professional opinions on what you recommend? etc. I would like to stick to ARM here as I have invested some time into understanding it etc. and all the boards I currently have are utilising ARM so it's nice to stick to this.

For my second question here; As a newbie to Electrical Engineering the part that really stalls me is the pins and their functions- I am aware of the different communication protocols and what they do, but there are many other pins on perhaps the ARM board that are not immediately intuitive and connecting the components I mentioned seems like a real challenge and i'm sure it is, so really my question is- are there any great resources to learn these pin functions or does someone have a pin cheat sheet they can point me to so I can advance my understanding on how these components connect with one another and work in an expected fashion. I do understand with every chip there comes a datasheet which one needs to look at but my misunderstanding seems to be coming before this step - probably because I do not have formal education in this domain. Thanks in advance.

ADDED INFO-
Operation or expected scenario of the board goes like this. User takes photo of them self using their phone as a controller connected via. bluetooth. Photo is taken and sent to the phone where X handles the rest of the process. So really this board has a job of (1) being connected via. bluetooth in bidirectional communication (2) displaying various lights such as red light on green light on etc. (3) playing a voice file that was sent from the users phone which will be played through an audio out speaker.

Comment: Draw a block diagram of a board with all of the interfaces it needs to support. This will define the *peripherals* you need. Peripherals are the ones who are defining the "pins". But you are talking about ARM *core* which does not have such peripherals, but serves as a computation and control unit for these. So this difference is the first important thing to understand here.

Comment: Welcome!  This question is both too broad and too much about part selection to belong here.  As a practical matter your project has requirements which will be extremely difficult to achieve with an MCU.  You probably need a single board computer - something like a raspberry pi but preferably without the Pi's storage and power design flaws.  These parts are too electrically and mechanically complex to economically put on custom boards until you have a large volume product, so you have to find an existing board or module to use.

Comment: @ChrisStratton this product should be about <75$ a unit it seems feasible taking into consideration the ARM-m7 chips are <10$ and the bluetooth <10$ I could do away with the LCD and just use the users phone for a UI.. that just leaves the camera. This is a question concealed as a statement though - let me know what you think please.

Comment: You're going to have trouble getting the camera going with an MCU.  It can be done, but you are in over your head trying to make it happen.  Things like buffer memory become a challenge, once you are no longer restricting yourself to on-chip memory you are effectively crossing the MCU-SoC divide.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Okay, i'm getting the feeling this part would be very hard :)

Comment: Well, a DSP could help. Depending on your camera interface and the in-built processing level of course (and the intended processing level on the board).

Comment: Are you making ONE board, 5 Boards, 200, or 10,000?

Comment: 10 boards initially as a prototype(s) for a new feature for our app. So with the intention of ordering N amount in the future - this depends of course on funding and if our users like this.. end goal would be something <75$ or so if we made 10,000 units or something within those lines. But the preconditions are still valid here, needs bluetooth, camera those cannot be dropped. Ideally cheap as possible ofcourse.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use something like a Raspberry Pi?  It seems to already have all the capabilities you are asking for and available for $25-$35.

Comment: @evildemonic         it's nice to have something of our own - there are pros and cons to each I suppose but as a start-up I can appreciate the fact I can use the pi to do this quickly but at the same time down the road if I need 10,000 units because there is demand i'm entirely reliant on raspberry pis and what they do/ how they do things. Also, if this is used commercially there seems to be a bit of a grey area there with them. i'm sure 100 units would be fine but not sure the intertwined complications of selling these in mass and being `built` into our platform/ product

Comment: @Invic18 this is what the Pi Compute Module is for

Comment: If you are trying to do this from scratch, both h/w and s/w, you should budget about a year of engineer time. If you are located in Europe or the USA that's around $60 per hour or about $100k for the project. I have worked on underbudgeted stuff with "workarounds" and "shortcuts", and its a nightmare

Comment: @DirkBruere that sounds about right. I would suggest that newbies read postmortems of some failed hardware kickstarters and then think carefully on whether they want to do this or hire expert assistance.

Comment: The functionality you describe in your "ADDED INFO" paragraph could be implemented entirely as an app on the smartphone. Why exactly do you need external hardware?

Comment: I completely agree with Dave that this is phone functionality, but I suspect the application needs two gadgets at a distance - ie, phone as a trigger for a remote camera.  I think the best way to proof-of-concept it would be to use a *second* phone (or the guts thereof) in a 3d printed over case and call it the product...

Comment: Same could be said for something like the Electron or even Alexa, but in my case this is going into a mirror that takes a picture of the upper torso so (1) needs to be in the same place and hands free (2) added attraction to the product in a sense there is a piece of hardware that makes the user have fun with it. There is more context and information on the UX side of things but I will void that from this response unless you're really curious.

Comment: If it's plugged into the wall your options increase dramatically.  Start with a cheap tablet or a pi, then you can look at the various Allwinner etc boards that compete with the pi but are made with parts more manufacturable and not SD-card dependent.  There's also the Octavo Beagle-on-a-module stuff.

Comment: Would be plugged in yes

Comment: I would like to ask though - A lot of the concern is coming over the camera module i'm a little bit more curious why this is such a problem? I am new to embedded so please forgive my lack of understanding initially - is it because of memory issues as well? taking a photo obviously there is a lot going on in there and working with a board with constrained memory would propose issues hold that data in RAM So I can understand this issue with RAM as well as potential driver? issue(s). Could you explain in better context exactly why this proposes so many challenges ?

Comment: Get *your idea* working with a pi 3 (or for that matter even a PC "behind the curtain") and you will learn where the issues are.

Answer (score 3):

My only suggestion is try and find an existing board that does what you want, and see what hardware they use. If the design and firmware is open source, then you have your solution with a bit of hacking. In my experience the hardest part is programming the pins and on-chip peripherals

Comment: You mean getting all the components communicating with one another in an appropriate order?

Comment: To see if you can hook up the peripherals, but also to see if you can fit your application's needs into constrained memory.  Very constrained one you start talking about pictures or video if you insist on going the MCU route.  To some extent, what you should probably do is just find a cheap phone, put a custom/cut down OS on it and call it your product.  A small trailing edge phone or tablet SoC would be the right place to look if you get to the eventual point of making something custom.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice

Comment: @Invic18 You are probably going to need an operating system to hook up all of those devices seamlessly

Comment: @DirkBruere would this be too much to do bare metal in your opinion? I mean, as a  web/ai startup I much prefer using a light Linux version, but just feeling things out.

Comment: @Invic18 light linux version makes the software much easier, but anything with enough RAM to run Linux has external DRAM, so you need a reasonable level of board design skill to make that work at all.

Comment: @Invic18 Linux is preferable, but if you are pushed for space check out FreeRTOS. We use it at work and it runs comfortably on small boards with not much memory eg 256K flash + 64K RAM

Answer (score 1):

> I am aware of the different communication protocols and what they do, but there are many other pins on perhaps the ARM board that are not immediately intuitive and connecting the components I mentioned seems like a real challenge and i'm sure it is, so really my question is- are there any great resources to learn these pin functions or does someone have a pin cheat sheet they can point me to so I can advance my understanding on how these components connect with one another and work in an expected fashion. I do understand with every chip there comes a datasheet which one needs to look at but my misunderstanding seems to be coming before this step - probably because I do not have formal education in this domain. Thanks in advance.

Well, the datasheet *is* the explanation. If you get the proper datasheet this will be pretty comprehensive; I worked with an iMX53 that had a 1,500 page full manual covering all the functions. It had a lot of functions.

For your project, the camera will be a serious problem. You need to find what camera interface it has; this is usually [CSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_Serial_Interface). Then you need to find a chip with a CSI peripheral.

Comment: That was the daunting thing coming to embedded the datasheets are huge but necessary obviously. Is there another go-to you guys use though? or mostly pre-existing knowledge with the datasheet. You guys are scaring me with this camera here, unfortunately that's basically the most important part

Comment: Usually we shop around for evaluation boards having the capabilities close enough for our requirements, looking at their details, and then, if it is an overkill, then looking for the processor (and other components) "siblings" and "cusins" and stripping it down to whatever we need.

Comment: that's great advice on how you guys do things, thanks

Comment: Teardowns (e.g. ifixit) are a good source of information; another very useful thing to know about is "parametric search" on Digikey and other vendors.

Answer (score 1):

Before you think of what hardware you need to put together, you should think about **what software you are going to need to run all of that** stuff.

As many have mentioned in the comments, from the sounds of it, this is not a weekend project, and this is going to cost you a handsomely amount of money, but most importantly time.

My suggestion to you is **use something like a Raspberry Pi CM4 for now**. Not only do you get a lot of power and peripherals for that price, but you also get the ability to **boot GNU Linux** on it. **Writting software for all of those peripherals is no fun**, or maybe it is, but why re-invent the wheel?

Building a carrier board for this will also be much cheaper AND faster. Spinning out a couple of revisions for a carrier board will hurt you much less than throwing away a $20 MCU or a $40 MPU (RAM, etc) if you make a tiny mistake, or if the dimensions aren't quite right

Considering you are still doubtful of the different interfaces used, your chances of getting EVERYTHING right the first time are not very likely.

Choose function over form. Creating a board from scratch is cool and all but that's not the purpose of what you're doing.